# left value in CSS with center as base line?

Tags: css, responsive-design, alignment, center

Is it possible to use the center of a page as a base line to position something? I think the best way to explain what I would want would be something in the lines of:

```
#div{
margin-left:auto + 85px ;
margin-right:auto;}
```

I hope I'm being clear. I'm not that good at coding and English is also not my native language. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: How about using `position:relative` with `left:75px`? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gEvLz/)

Comment: Create a [JsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with your current code for a faster and more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first center the element and then offset it by your desired amount. Something like this should do the job:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;

  background-color: pink;
}
```

This absolutely centers an element. If you want if further to the left, just increase the negative margin-left.

Simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/McBLg/

Edit: fixed brainbug (mixing left & right directions)